# Is Drupal Cache Warmer for real?

Tags: caching, proxies

I am using  Varnish + Default Page cache with a expiring time (1 day) in a site.

When I am browsing the site, everything seems loading fine; once I come back to the site after a day or so, the the pages start loading slow and they become okay after a while.

It seems like the cache is being cleared after a while and generated again once someone visit the site again. I do not want that user to suffer.

I read about **Drupal Cache Warmer**; is there something which can keep the cache alive and no user suffers?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You should report exactly what you mean by _Drupal Cache Warmer_, in your question.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Drupal caches the pages for anonymous users; authenticated users would probably not see much improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's the [Cache Warmer](https://www.drupal.org/project/cache_warmer) module you can set up if you have drush access on your server.

You can also use a 3rd party service like [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/) to do that as well.

Comment: okay great i will try these.

Comment: Do you have any idea what Drupal is doing if the site gets visited after many hours first time. (i meant page loads very slow. is it running cron or caching pages ?). Is there a way to stop this behavior .

Answer (score 0):

See following for good description of Drupal caching and how cache is flushed on cron run.

http://tomroelandts.com/articles/how-to-ensure-that-visitors-always-see-cached-pages-in-drupal-7

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.